# Encrypted System Partition Failed to Load on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: boot, encryption, initramfs, dash-shell

I have a laptop (Thinkpad L520) with 256 GB SSD drive with Ubuntu 17.04 on it (no other operating system installed). The drive is encrypted with means of Ubuntu installation medium. One day the system freezes and after boot send me to (initramfs) (see screenshot below). I also have a possibility to log in through live USB and see and decrypt the drive (with an error that operating system not found, but I still apparently can access the data).

I don't think that my SSD drive is corrupted, although I am ready to change my mind if some kind if diagnostic will be suggested to me. I think it was a problem with a system update, and that I haven't used to reboot my laptop too often. I have read on other topics that the kernel update might be the issue.

here is boot-repair summary (although I have been trying to 'fix' it using their operational procedure, am not sure I broke anything any more than it was): https://paste.ubuntu.com/24985651/

UPDATE: [image: initramfs screenshot]
UPD2: fsck -f /dev/sda5
fsck from util-linux 2.29
(initramfs)

Apropos SSD firmware diagnostic:

Here is the model and other data I was able to gather from Ubuntu. The manufacturer website send me to the software that is not supported by Linux, apparently. https://paste.ubuntu.com/25046170/

Gparted:

Gparted gives me the following error right from the start: 
The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.

[image: Gparted screenshot]

What I would like to do:

I would like to restore full functionality of my system, as I already have invested some time in configuration. Or I need to know how to find all of the files belong to me (in what folder to look) in order to reinstall the system. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @heynnema please consult.

Comment: See my partial answer. "unknown filesystem" is a little scary, but it may say that due to the encryption. Did you change your complete configuration from before? fstab looks totally different, etc.

Comment: @heynnema I was tryed boot-repair to fix the problem, that is why, perhaps.

Comment: Something else has changed since your June 5th question that I helped you with an encrypted swap. This configuration is using LVM and encryption. Why the diff? Did you reinstall? Edit your question to include a screenshot of `gparted` of your hard drive. It's not looking good right now. Have you checked your SSD firmware yet?

Comment: ps: see my answer, step #2

Answer (score 1):

Since you've recently had other/similar problems, it's important for me to say we'll need to check the firmware in your SSD. You'll need to go to the manufacturer's web site to see if there are updates.

Let's first perform a file system check. There's at least 3 different ways to do this. We'll try the easy way first, and then try others if need be. Let me say that LVM and encryption make this job somewhat difficult, and I'm not an expert on either. That said...

**Step #1:**

Since you're at the `(initramfs)` prompt...

```
type "exit"
note the name of the hard disk called out...
in your case, it'll probably be something like "/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root"
type "fsck -f /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root"
```

Then try and reboot your system.

**Step #2:**

Since you're at the `(initramfs)` prompt...

```
type "exit"
type "fsck -f /dev/sda5"
```

Then try and reboot your system.

**Update #1:**

Mounted the encrypted Ubuntu partition and backed up user files, and then reinstalled Ubuntu.

Comment: here is the output (see update in my question)

Comment: please see my second update, the system returns me to initramfs without a visible change to the operational success.

Comment: @parakovsky I never did get an answer to my question "Something else has changed since your June 5th question that I helped you with an encrypted swap. This configuration is using LVM and encryption. Why the diff?".

Comment: it was the same configuration.

Comment: Try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if you can mount your disk from there. If you can, you can try to backup important files and then reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: i am sorry, i am unintentionally misderected you with my previos answer, I have been using two computers with Ubuntu at the same time, and they both have an previous issue with freezing - that you helpted to resolve, the machine in question now is have a drive and user folder encrypted. I would like to avoid reinstall and fix the issue with initramfs, if possible.

Comment: @parakovsky  Go ahead and try booting to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if you can access your files on the SSD/HDD. At least that'll tell us if the partition is OK. Please remember to start comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: yes I can access the SSD from Live USB (thought I mentioned it before here) I am unable to access the files of my user, I didn't know how, yet. Although I would like to just restore my system without reinstalling everything, it would be also good to know how to do this.

Comment: If you open a `Files` (Nautilus) window, you should be able to mount the drive by clicking once on its name in the left pane. It should then ask you for a password. Then navigate to your home folder, and you should see your files/folders.

Comment: thank you. I was able to do that. Now I am just reinstall the system. Again, thanks for your answers, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's just not worth the time to try to restore stuff, I was able to boot and access my encrypted drive from LIVE USB, navigate to my user folder and just copy important stuff and then reinstall everything. I hope it wouldn't happen again, thought.